# Adobe Acrobat Javascript Promises

Tags: javascript, adobe

Is it possible to use promises with Javascript in Adobe Acrobat?  I am currently using the functions that receives an 'OnSuccess' parameter to execute synchronously.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Thank you for the willingness to help.  However my current code is working, I just wanted to know whether or not promises are possible in Acrobat's Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acrobat uses the `SpiderMonkey 1.8` JavaScript engine, and promises are a feature of ECMAscript 2015. The javascript engine that acrobat uses is old (read 8 years old), and therefore does not support promises

[Javascript 1.8 age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript#JavaScript_versions)

[Javascript for acrobat](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html)

[Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Specifications)

Comment: Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20180602050948/https://helpx.adobe.com/in/acrobat/using/whats-new-dc-2015.html#additional_enhancements